# Why does Google Pay require location permission?

Tags: location-services, google-pay

Google Pay uses mobile numbers and UPI to transact money.

Why does it require location permissions?

Comment: One thing that I want to know, but can't since Google Pay is not supported in my country: can you do a transaction with location service disabled?

Comment: no.. we cannot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Google Pay is more than just for payments. One of its features (or bloat) is that it can find jobs for you based on your profile and location, et al.

Per [Google Pay Help:](https://support.google.com/pay/india/answer/9491472?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=9460371)

> **How do I find specific types of jobs?**
>
> We recommend jobs for you based on your profile info, location, preferences and your activity in the app.
>
> To find specific types of jobs, make sure that you update your profile info, location and preferences to reflect the sort of jobs that you’re interested in.

Comment: does that make location permission necessary for payments?

Comment: It seems to require it under the pretense of detecting suspicious activity.

Comment: This is yet another reason I choose to avoid Google products whenever possible (which is pretty much always).  Too many intrusive permissions by a data hoarding mega-corporation.  See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231091/google-pay-scanning-credit-card-without-camera-permission