# Google pay scanning credit card without camera permission

Tags: google, google-pay

I have [Google Pay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel) installed on my phone. I have denied camera permission for every single app (except for "Settings" app which I am unable to deny Camera permission) on my phone.

When I try to add payment method on Google Pay app, Google Pay app is able to use my phone camera to scan credit card without camera permission. How is this possible?

Comment: Is it a system app? Came with the phone? In which case it has elevated privileges

Comment: It's a Google app. Letting you "play" with its permissions often is "window dressing". I've seen it more than once that it seemed to have no effect. There's always Google Play Services on your device, which is a system app and thus… see what @beeshyams wrote. Unless of course you'd have a Google-free device. But that you'd not use Google Pay.

Comment: @beeshyams It came with the phone but I doubt it is a system app. I am able to uninstall Google Pay and reinstall it from play store.

Comment: @Izzy I am looking for something more technical. How does Google app access Camera API without getting `java.lang.SecurityException` due to lack of camera permission? Do they use a different set of APIs that regular app developer has no access to? If the camera functionality comes from Google Play Services and Google Pay merely invoke Google Play services, is it possible for a regular app to invoke this functionality from Google Play Services as well (as a proof of concept for e.g.)?

Comment: It's closed source, so hard to look inside. But yes, there are parts of APIs only available to system apps, or apps signed with the same key. This I suspect in several situations (like Google apps re-enabling themselves despite of having been explicitly disabled by the user, for example).

Comment: I have seen multiple different Google apps give themselves permissions after the user has denied them permission.  However, in those cases, you can see Google has given their apps permissions behind your back.  This case seems a bit different as the OP seems to be indicating that the permission is still denied, but the Google app is able to use the camera.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket correct, the permission still remain denied yet Google Pay is still able to access camera function.

Comment: Thank you for confirming.  That's downright horrible, and I actually wonder if it is illegal in some jurisdictions.  That's a huge privacy violation.

Comment: Can you provide the output of the command `adb shell appops get com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel` and `adb shell appops query-op CAMERA allow` ?

Comment: In addition, try using Google Pay again. If you still see it being able to use your camera despite being denied to do so, log/note the current time and than share the output of these two commands along with saved timestamp. `adb shell dumpsys appops --op CAMERA` and `adb shell dumpsys appops --package com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel`

Comment: Google Pay is not available in my country, so I can't really test it. That said, is the scanning done directly in Google Pay app (like a partial window for scanning QR), or a different full-screen page/activity? The first one shouldn't happen without camera permission, but the second one might hint at utilizing an external app/service for the camera.

Comment: @Firelord Great advice! `com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel` is not listed for `adb shell appops query-op CAMERA allow`, I assume this means that camera functionality is denied for `com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel`. Using `adb shell dumpsys appops --op CAMERA`, I see that only `com.google.android.gms` is utilizing camera at the timestamp when I scan credit card using Google Pay.

`com.google.android.gms` has camera permission enabled. Google Pay scan credit card function cease to work when camera permission for `com.google.android.gms` is denied.

Comment: Okay. What does this command shows: `adb shell 'dumpsys package com.google.android.gms | sed -n "/Shared users/,/install permissions/p"'`

Comment: @Firelord 
```Shared users:
  SharedUser [com.google.uid.shared] (cb42841):
    userId=10025
    Packages
      PackageSetting{3271bb9 com.google.android.gsf/10025}
      PackageSetting{8096980 com.google.android.gms/10025}
    install permissions:
```

Comment: That is a dead end for me. I think we have to try Andrew's approach now. My suggestion is to find out what activity ends up in foreground when your Google Pay is scanning a credit card.

Comment: @Firelord I hope all the comments here are never deleted as they are quite valuable.  Your comments, especially, are very helpful and educational.  Perhaps some of them can even be included in an eventual answer.

Comment: @Firelord I did a `adb shell dumpsys activity` and got some info. The card scanning is from `SecuredCreditCardOcrActivity` in `com.google.android.gms`. I think we have answered my question. Feel free to create an answer for this and I will accept it.

Comment: Not really a part of this question but I am curious about the mechanism to start `com.google.android.gms` `SecuredCreditCardOcrActivity`. I am guessing it is using either a `BroadcastReceiver` or via explicit `Intent`. Is it possible for a non google app to start `SecuredCreditCardOcrActivity` by replicating the same mechanism?

Comment: May I know the last activity's name on Google Pay before it delegates to `SecuredCreditCardOcrActivity`? I'm trying to "debug" the APK using Android Studio (not really full reverse-engineering) and see if I can get some hints from there, or maybe you can see from the logcat how it fires the `Intent`?

Comment: @AndrewT. The task stack is `com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel/com.google.commerce.tapandpay.android.cardlist.CardListActivity` -> `com.google.android.gms/.tapandpay.tokenization.TokenizePanActivity` -> `com.google.android.gms/.tapandpay.tokenization.AddNewCardForTokenizationActivity` -> `com.google.android.gms/.wallet.im.ImRootActivity` -> `com.google.android.gms/.ocr.SecuredCreditCardOcrActivity` with `SecuredCreditCardOcrActivity` being the top most activity. I am guessing we only have to start `TokenizePanActivity` and `com.google.android.gms` will take it from there.